# combo box list that uses textbox to add values to cells

Tags: excel, combobox

I am trying to do something simple but I can't seem to get it right as I am new to this.

[image: this is my list]

I want to select a name from the list and then add a value through the **`textbox`** to the cells next to the items, for example should I type 1 for John, I want it placed next to his name. Ideally I want each entry for john to move to the next column , for example after 1 should I enter 2, I want the value to appear in **`C1`** etc.

I've tried many things but nothing works, I would really appreciate some help with this or some pointers as to what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi hollopost and thanks!Unfortunately I am new here and I don't have the required reputation to include images directly in my posts. I hope that my image and my description makes my question specific enough to be answered though !